# PL/SQL : Should i use a collection or do multiple querys?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, collections, plsql

I'm working on this project where i need to create a big HTML table where each table row is a 15 minute interval and every table column is a day. The goal is to show users that want to reserve rooms when the room is available and not. All the webpages are PL/SQL packages that print out the proper HTML.

Example of a table for a certain room :

[image]

(don't mind the different colors)

All the room definitions are stored into an oracle database containing a start date, an end date, Starting hour, ending hour and days of the week. So for example a definition could be:
(07-31-2013 - 07-31-2014, 00:00 - 23:59, Mondays,Tuesdays and Fridays)

My concern is that to build every square of my html table, i need to make a query to check if that specific period is defined. (For example if the user wants to see a full week from 10:00 to 14:00 for a room, 112 querys will be made to build the table with 15 minute intervals) Not to mention that a user can see up to 4 weeks and from any time interval (could be from 00:00 to 23:59). Another problem is that i need to make that check for room definitions but i also have to make another check as many times to see if that interval is taken by a reservation... So that make 224 querys only to see a week.

My solution was to get all the room definitions and reservations that could affect the period that the user wants to see and put them in a collection(1 collection for definitions and 1 for reservations). After that, i run all my tests on those collection without doing a query. My main procedure calls a Function sending both collections as a parameter and the function return true or false.

**I was wondering if oracle could handle that many small requests or did i do the right thing with the collections ?**

I read many posts saying how collections were bad for memory and i'm scared that passing them through a function parameter might not help either... Altough it might no apply to my situation considering the collection will probably never have more then 1-5 records in them.

My query to check if it is available or not would be something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'Y' 
FROM room_defenition
WHERE
START_DATE <= USER_DATE AND 
END_DATE >= USER_DATE AND
--F_TO_DAY converts the date to the coresponding code
REGEXP_INSTR(MON||TUE||WED||THU||FRI||SAT||SUN,F_TO_DAY(USER_DATE)) <> 0 AND
START_TIME <= USER_START_TIME AND 
END_TIME >= USER_END_TIME;
```

USER_DATE would be the current column i'm testing on and USER_START_TIME and USER_END_TIME would be the two border of the current interval. (example 07-31-2013 - 10:00 - 10:15).

I also have 2 subquerys in the where clause to check if the user is allowed to make reservations on this room or not...

Comment: I'm not going to be of much help here, but what do your queries look like?

Comment: Added how my queries would be if i would'nt use collections

Answer (score 3):

One solution to do this kind of stuff is to create tables called dimensions. Your array has two dimensions so you would create two tables, one called `QUARTERS` for example, that has one row for each 15 min in a day (so 96 rows)

```
id    timestart   timeend
-----------------
1      00:00  00:15
2      00:15  00:30
...
```

and one called `CALENDAR` that holds days for the whole year (or for the next 10 years, it doesn't matter)

```
id    dateofday
---------------
1     01/01/2013
2     02/01/2013
...
```

It's easy to build a query that gives exactly one row for each cell of your array, no matter if there are or not available rooms.

```
select timestart, timeend, dateofday
from quarters cross join calendar -- a legitimate use for cross join
where timestart >= user_time_start and
      timeend   <= user_time_end and
      dateofday between user_date_start and user_date_end 
order by quarters.id, calendar.id
```

Result are ordered by rows of your array, then column. So you can read the results of the query one row at a time and build your array on the fly (no need for collection or complex algorithm)

Now you just need to add a subquery that tells you if the room is available or not, something like :

```
select timestart, timeend, dateofday,
    (*subquery on room_definition *) available
    from quarters cross join calendar -- a legitimate use for cross join
    where timestart >= user_time_start and
          timeend   <= user_time_end and
          dateofday between user_date_start and user_date_end 
    order by quarters.id, calendar.id
```

Comment: I think i understand your concept but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of not making a bunch of queries or sub-queries in this case ? Correct me if i'm wrong but wouldn't that "(*subquery on room_definition *)" be evaluated for as many times as i have squares in my HTML table ?

Comment: I don't really know how Oracle will run the subquery, you'd have to run an explain plan. But all the data will be read, prepared and sorted in Oracle and that's something it is build for and does pretty well. Plus you eliminate the overhead from preparing a query, opening a cursor, reading the results, closing the cursor,...

Comment: +1 although I'd look at possibly using an outer join to room_definition instead of a select clause - but it depends.